# Cant recognise where is my targeted function executed

Tags: ida, x86-64, game-hacking

Im trying to recognise where is my targeted function `int64 __fastcall sub_1400CE4F0(__int64 a1, const char *a2)`executed. When stepping through this function, after `return` it's redirecting me here:

```
if ( *(_QWORD *)(v9 + v8 + 8) || *(_QWORD *)(v9 + v8 + 16) )
  (*(void (__fastcall **)(_QWORD, __int64))(v9 + v8 + 16))(*(_QWORD *)(v9 + v8 + 8), v4);
if ( v5 == 0xFFFFFFF ) //Here..
  v5 = *((_DWORD *)v2 + 9);
```

1. Where is this function executed? Am I in the right place?
2. Is it hidden in those cast's? How can I understand them? (Maybe it's hidden in those casts?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the line:

`(*(void (__fastcall **)(_QWORD, __int64))(v9 + v8 + 16))(*(_QWORD *)(v9 + v8 + 8), v4);`

That you have an indirect function call - a function that is called by a value of a variable, and not by a direct address.

Your function has the following signature:

`void your_func(QWORD, __int64)`

And the function itself comes from the `v9 + v8 + 16` variables.

So `v9 + v8 + 8` is the first parameter of the function, and `v4` is the second parameter.

Comment: wow, sounds good. Thanks for help.